# I can't finish building the apk " Error: GraphQL request failed."

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, apk

I want to create an Android application, but when I start the steps, I see several problems in the visual studio code terminal:PS C:\Users\motas\OneDrive\Desktop\0> npm i -g eas-cli
npm WARN deprecated @oclif/screen@3.0.8: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.

changed 409 packages in 6s

38 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details
PS C:\Users\motas\OneDrive\Desktop\0> eas build -p android
Loaded "env" configuration for the "production" profile: no environment variables specified. Learn more: https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/variables/
You don't have the required permissions to perform this operation.

Entity not authorized: AccountEntity[47080584-8e6e-4a02-91fe-e8f9d3f6163e] (viewer = RegularUserViewerContext[0497e058-edff-461b-8d3b-81919b730305], action = READ, ruleIndex = -1)
Request ID: 11f8b16b-956a-4cb6-8eb0-6edce504e1d7
Error: GraphQL request failed.
PS C:\Users\motas\OneDrive\Desktop\0>
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbKtv.png)

I want to create an Android application, but when I start the steps, I see several problems in the visual studio code terminal
PS C:\Users\motas\OneDrive\Desktop\0> eas build -p android
Loaded "env" configuration for the "production" profile: no environment variables specified. Learn more: https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/variables/
You don't have the required permissions to perform this operation.

Entity not authorized: AccountEntity[47080584-8e6e-4a02-91fe-e8f9d3f6163e] (viewer = RegularUserViewerContext[0497e058-edff-461b-8d3b-81919b730305], action = READ, ruleIndex = -1)
Request ID: 11f8b16b-956a-4cb6-8eb0-6edce504e1d7
Error: GraphQL request failed.